# Uniform Stability of a linear system

Tags: control, linear

For the system $$ \dot{x}(t) = A(t)x(t),\quad x(t_0) = x_0\quad (1)$$ 
we say it's uniformly stable **if** $$\exists \gamma : ||x(t)|| \leq \gamma ||x_0||\quad t \geq t_0\quad \forall t_0,x_0$$

However, from the state transition matrix context, (1) is said to be uniformly stable **iff** $$ \exists \gamma : ||\phi(t,\tau)|| \leq \gamma \quad t\geq\tau\quad \forall t,\tau$$

Since $$x(t) = \phi(t,t_0)x_0$$, I'm wondering what explains the 'if' and 'iff' discrepancy. Reference: Wilson Rugh's Linear Systems

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to distinguish "if" from "iff" when we're talking about defining a term. If this is the definition of the term then the definition of the term is this, so the "and only if" is implied even if we just say "if".

Comment: This is better than your last question because now we're talking about stability in a system, which is an electrical engineering topic. The last question you asked was considered purely math because there was no indication of how you're utilizing it in the engineering field.